# Whole file isn’t executing after updating webpack to v5.64.2

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-5

I upgraded webpack and since then no script is executed when starting the app.

I put console log and brake point, but it does not stop and does not log in the console.

Webpack is updated from v4.43.0 to v5.64.2.

The console log is located in the code when the bundled file is opened in the browser.

```
    entry: {
        'app-plugin': './js/app-plugin',
    },
...
{
    entry: {
        'app-bundle': './js/app-bundle',
    },
    mode: 'development',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                use: [
                    {loader: 'script-loader'},
                ],
                exclude: [/node_modules/, XLIBS_PATH],
            },
        ],
    },
}
```

Build goes without a problem as well as launching the application.

Does anyone know why the code is not executing after the update? I am assuming that some config parameter is missing, but I can't find which one.